# Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function coffeescript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Here `searchData` is an array of elements.I think the problem is with `source`.but cannot figure it out.Help me in finding what is causing error here.
Below is the Array i am using.The array below is fetched from a json file using `get request`.

```
searchData = ["Ruby", "Python", "Java", "C++", "C", "Haskell", "Go", "Scala", "Pascal", "PHP", "Objective-C", "Lisp", "Groovy"]

$.get("/scrolls/search_suggestions.json").done (searchData) ->
    console.log(searchData)
    $("#name").autocomplete ->
        source: searchData
        select: (event,ui) ->
        log if ui.item then 'Selected: '+ui.item.value+' aka '+ ui.item.id else 'Nothing selected, input was ' + @value
        return
      return
```

I am taking this page as reference:[Here](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/default.html).Find the array named `availableTags` in page source code.

Comment: Assuming this is using jQueryUI Autocomplete, what you have should work. Your 'reference page' link isn't working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan .Added the URL.Sorry for missing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me.
In the above i interpreted this `$("#name").autocomplete ->` as function.But it is function call.I changed it to `$("#name").autocomplete`.This worked for me.

```
$.get("/scrolls/search_suggestions.json").done (searchData) ->
    console.log(searchData)
    $("#name").autocomplete
        source: searchData
        select: (event,ui) ->
        log if ui.item then 'Selected: '+ui.item.value+' aka '+ ui.item.id else 'Nothing selected, input was ' + @value
 return
```

Hope.Someday It will help someone.